# What is wrong with the last line of code here?

Tags: ios

Am trying to set up a view hierarchy in the viewDidLoad method, and am getting a problem with the last line.

```
UIView *catView = [[UIView alloc] init];


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lolcat.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting when the last line runs?

Comment: Why are you allocating catView, what is your plan with it?

Comment: It says: "Remember that you need to add a subview and not insert a subview."

Comment: what is your error and what would you like to do?

Comment: This is part of a code challenge, and the first line is already provided. I have written the following three challenges. Lines 2, 3 passed the code challenge fine, it's only line 4 which is returning the error. The instructions for line 4 are: "Add the UIImageView as a subview to the instance of UIView named 'catView'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to change

```
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

to

```
[catView addSubview:imageView];
```

See https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/programming-a-background-stuck-on-code-challenge